# pure binary editor (not a hex editor) does it exist?

Tags: binary, editor

Can anyone tell me if there is already a pure binary reader/editor (not a HEX editor) readily available on the internet?

After an exhaustive search on the internet, I could not find a single one!

I know I can probably write a script to do that, but just curious if anyone knows of any that already exist?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a "pure binary editor"?

Comment: sorry novice lingo in active there.... I mean a binary editor (not a hex) because most of the HEX editors out there are termed as binary editor. (reader capable of displaying binary bits)

Comment: huh? Are you sure you want to edit something like: 1010100001001111010101010111110101010111011010101101010101010010100100101010101010101111110000000111110101010111010101100000111101001010010100101100 ?

Comment: not edit but be able to view

Answer (score 0):

The reason there don't exist any is because hex displays the same thing as the binary, but in a more compact and readable form.  Every pair of hex digits equals eight binary digits.

You just need to read hex as the binary that it is.  11110000 is F0, 00001111 is 0F.  If you must though, xxd has a binary option:

```
$ xxd -b binaryIShex 
0000000: 01100010 01101001 01101110 01100001 01110010 01111001  binary
0000006: 00100000 01001001 01010011 00100000 01101000 01100101   IS he
000000c: 01111000 00100001 00001010                             x!.

$ xxd binaryIShex 
0000000: 6269 6e61 7279 2049 5320 6865 7821 0a    binary IS hex!.
```

Bless is also able to do it, but you need to edit the default layout according to 
[Layout Help](http://home.gna.org/bless/bless-manual/ch05s03.html):
[Bless with binary user defined layout http://i.minus.com/i1pMAx6lWN7q1.png](http://i.minus.com/i1pMAx6lWN7q1.png).